# Rails form won't select default value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

Rails 4.0 Ruby 2.0, SimpleForm 3.1.0.rc2

Why isn't the default value selected in the first example when It is selected in the second example?  Both examples are in the same form.  More to the point, I suppose, is how do I fix it?  Thanks.

```
<%= f.input(:location_id, {input_html: {value: @car.location}, collection: Location.all.order("name").collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, prompt: "Location?"}) %>

<select id="car_location_id" class="select optional form-control form-control" value="Rcving" name="car[location_id]">
<option value="">Location?</option>
‌<option value="7">Manager</option>
‌<option value="9">Rcving</option>
‌<option value="8">Return</option>
‌<option value="10">RollBack</option>
‌<option value="6">Stock</option>
</select>

<%= f.input(:ymm_year_id, {input_html: {value: @car.year}, collection: YmmYear.all.order("year desc").collect{|c| [c.year, c.id]}, prompt: "Year?"}) %>

<select id="car_ymm_year_id" class="select optional form-control form-control" value="2013" name="car[ymm_year_id]">
<option value="9">2015</option>
‌<option value="10">2014</option>
‌<option value="8" selected="selected">2013</option>
‌<option value="7">2012</option>
‌<option value="6">2011</option>
‌<option value="5">2010</option>
‌<option value="2">2009</option>
‌<option value="4">2008</option>
‌<option value="1">2007</option>
‌<option value="3">2006</option>
‌<option value="13">2005</option>
‌<option value="17">2004</option>
‌<option value="14">2003</option>
‌<option value="11">2002</option>
‌<option value="16">2001</option>
‌<option value="15">2000</option>
‌<option value="12">1999</option>
</select>
```

The form is:

```
<div class="span8">
  <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @car],
                      defaults: {label: false},
                      html: {class: 'form-vertical'},
                      wrapper: :vertical_form,
                      wrapper_mappings: {
                              check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              file: :vertical_file_input,
                              boolean: :vertical_boolean
                      } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input(:stock_number, {input_html: {value: @car.stock_number},  disabled: true, autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Stock number?'}) %>
      <%= f.input(:ymm_year_id, {input_html: {value: @car.year}, collection: YmmYear.all.order("year desc").collect{|c| [c.year, c.id]}, prompt: "Year?"}) %>
      <%= f.input(:ymm_make_id, {input_html: {value: @car.make}, collection: YmmMake.makes(@car.ymm_year_id).collect{|c| [c.make, c.id]}, prompt: "Make?"}) %>
      <%= f.input(:ymm_model_id, {input_html: {value: @car.model}, collection: YmmModel.models(@car.ymm_make_id).collect{|c| [c.model, c.id]}, prompt: "Model?"}) %>
      <%= f.association(:color, {input_html: {value: @car.color}, autocomplete: :off, prompt: 'Color?'}) %>
      <%= f.input(:location_id, {input_html: {value: @car.location}, collection: Location.all.order("name").collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, prompt: "Location?"}) %>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <br/>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
        <br/><br/>
      <%= link_to 'Delete Car', admin_car_path(@car), class: 'btn btn-warning', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Example JQuery running with form:

```
$("select[name='car[ymm_year_id]']").change(function () {
    // send a GET request to /ymm_makes with the 'year' parameter
    $.getJSON("/ymm_makes", {year: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
        var options_html = ['<option value="">Make?</option>'];
        // iterate over the JSON that we received back; each entry is one 'ymm_make'
        $.each(data, function (index, make) {
            if (index = 0) {options_html.push('<option value="">Make?</option>');}
            // make a new <option> tag for each make and push it into the options_html array
            options_html.push("<option value='" + make.id + "'>" + make.make + "</option>");
        });
        // put all our generated <options> tags into the <select> tag
        $('select#car_ymm_make_id').html(options_html.join('')).prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

EDIT: Modified code using variable without id:

```
<%= f.input(:location, {collection: Location.all.order("name").collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, prompt: "Location?"}) %>
<select id="car_location" class="select optional form-control form-control" name="car[location]">
<option value="7">Manager</option>
<option value="9">Rcving</option>
<option value="8">Return</option>
<option value="10">RollBack</option>
<option value="6">Stock</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a value set on `@car.location`? I'm wondering if it's selecting the default from the `value` attribute?

Comment: @maxshelley.  Sure, the value="Rcving" is actually rendered from the value of car.location directly.  Same as value="2013" for the year.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the `selected` option explicitly to the input? i.e.`<%= f.input(:location_id, {input_html: {value: @car.location}, collection: Location.all.order("name").collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, prompt: "Location?"}), selected: @car.location %>`

Comment: @maxshelley  Syntactically, I had to put it inside the brackets.  Thought it was going to work because the prompt disappeared, replaced by the first item on the list.  Sadly, that's all it did.  It did not actually "select" a field, just displayed the first item on the list and not the desired one.

Comment: Sorry, that was me typing too quickly and not checking where that bracket was. What renders if you remove `value` from the `input_html` hash? A `<select>` shouldn't need a value as it's selected `<option>` is the value (I think).

Comment: @R_G for form helpers, you should use the association itself, not the association ID - i.e., use `f.input(:ymm_model)`, not `f.input(:ymm_model_id)`. This way, you don't have to set the `:value` manually in `input_html`.

Comment: @mexshelley I tried about every permutation possible regarding selected, with value, without value, etc. with no success.  Thanks.

Comment: @janfoeh  Okay, I see what you mean.  However, this did for me about what selected did.  It simply accessed the first item in the list, replacing the prompt.  This occurred with or without value or selected or both.  IDK why year is working but this isn't...  Thanks.

Comment: @janfoeh I added the modified code to the end.  FYI.

Comment: The form helpers are supposed to set `selected` automatically. If the `@car` in the form currently belongs_to YmmMake #5, then YmmMake #5 will be `selected` in the dropdown. As an aside: I'll say it again - drop SimpleForm. It's not helping you understand how Rails form helpers work; come back to it when you got that nailed down.

Comment: In your Javascript: why are you adding the "Make?" placeholder option twice?

Comment: @janfoeh  You answered it.  Location is polymorphic, so there is no "belongs to". I knew that but missed it. I guess I need to add a query to set it when the form loads.

Comment: @janfoeh OBTW, the first "Make?" placeholder is just a default.  It can probably be removed but doesn't hurt anything.  The second one triggers when the array is fired and creates the prompt that the user will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the location variable is polymorphic, there is no "belongs to" association from car.  Therefore, value will not be set.  To get this to happen, I developed a JQuery that fires on ready to grab the value, which is actually the ID of the select, and set the value, as follows:

```
<%= f.input(:location_id, {input_html: {value: @car.location_id}, collection: Location.all.order("name").collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, prompt: "Location?"}) %>

$("select[name='car[location_id]']").ready(function () {
    // Obtain the value attribute and set val parameter
    var location = $('#car_location_id').attr("value");
    $("#car_location_id").val(location);
});
```

Kudos to janfoeh for leading me to this.  OBTW, I tried this all using the location variable but the select needed the ID.